# Background disappears on PDF

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, webbrowser-control

Inside of my WPF application, I have embedded a WebBrowser control, which in turn uses the AxAcroPDFLib to load a, you guessed it, PDF. Typically this PDF will load just fine, however, after ten or so times of viewing the PDF, the background on the PDF (the 'form' part of the PDF) disappears. All the text is still there, but boxes, rows, grids, labels, etc. are all gone. At that point, the only way to ever see the background again is to restart the app.

The PDF is a form which I am populating from an XML file.

Has anyone seen anything like this before / have any ideas as to what may be happening?

Comment: Adobe is hard to automate but I got it working pretty stable using this link http://hugeonion.com/2009/04/06/displaying-a-pdf-file-within-a-wpf-application/.  In the end I had to turn that feature off as it was eating the Down Key event.  If someone or another app open Adobe.exe then it will also break it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a memory leak.

Have you checked the memory consumption?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. In the end, it did end up being a memory leak caused by the AxAcroPDF object not being disposed of properly.